# Read Timed Out installing Worklight

Tags: eclipse, installation, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have installed the relevant Java and Eclipse software.
I can get to the Market Place and locate the Worklight Developer Edition software.

The install get to approx. 50% and then I receive the following error:-

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

```
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.2.0.01-20141027-1531.jar.
Read timed out
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue today.I tried accessing the url (http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.2.0.01-20141027-1531.jar) directly through the browser and it showed an "Internal Server Error" message. Looks like the IBM site that hosts the repositories is down.

Comment: Try again at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a problem at the IBM server side. Sorry for the inconvenience but you'll need to wait until the network outage is resolved.

Please note this is not a question fitting to Stack Overflow...

Comment: Hi Idan, Thank you for your response.